# Can I set up a cron job on Ubuntu Phone

Tags: bash, ubuntu-touch, cron

I've been looking around, and can't find if Ubuntu Touch can run `cron`.

So my question is: Can it?

Also does it have a standard set of bash utils installed?

Comment: Not realy anything on the Internet about it, i've looked everywhere. :( Why don't ubuntu give a list of commands for the phone? :(

Answer (score 0):

Cron and many command line tools are available. It is however not possible to safe any changes made to crontab unless you make your system partition writeable.

The implications of making your system partition writeable and how to do it have been discussed in various posts.

A work around has been suggested in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/628357/crontab-on-ubuntu-phone-scheduling-synchronisations?lq=1) answer. It involves invoking a script with an infinite loop by upstart (from ~/.config/upstart/). If you are going to use the `sleep` command in this script, you may want to consider that `sleep` currently behaves different to what you might expect.