# Crontab on Ubuntu Phone - Scheduling synchronisations

Tags: sync, cron, phone, schedule

On my Aquaris E4.5 I have successfully configured syncevolution to synchronise my CardDav Contacts and CalDav Calender entries.

Now I would like to schedule synchronisations. However, since `/var/spool/cron` is on the root filesystem, which is read only cron does not work, and I do not want to make the root filesystem read-write since I do want to be able to do updates.

Are there plans to maybe move the cron stuff into it's own mountpoint, so it can be made read-write such as many of the other mounts? Or is there some other way of scheduling?

Comment: I can't help but am very interested in any answer to that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [How to autostart a shell script on Ubuntu-touch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613557/how-to-autostart-a-shell-script-on-ubuntu-touch)

Hacky solution is to create an upstart script in /usr/share/upstart/sessions/ or ~/.config/upstart/ (that is writable)

```
description "my script"
start on started unity8-dash 

exec /path/to/your/script
```

and have an infinite loop that makes updates there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Since /usr/share/upstart is on the root filesystem too it is read-only as well. 

And since I do not want to set this to read-write, this is not a a feasible solution for me.

Comment: Yes, haven't verified that answer.

Comment: I found it myself, I have to place the file in .config/upstart directory, so it can be run in user context.