# How to run a terminal command after login (in Ubuntu Touch)

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-touch

I'm currently using a Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition.
Sure, it's working normally, but there's a terminal command that I want it to run everytime I boot my phone.

The command is: `gsettings set com.canonical.Unity8 usage-mode Windowed`

For those who doesn't know, this command enable the windowed mode in the phone.

I've tried various methods that I searched here and on the internet, but none of them worked.

- Creating/Modifying the ~/.bash_login or .bash_profile didn't work.
- Trying to modify /etc/rc.local is not a option, since I have to mount it as RW (but I don't want to do that because I still want to receive OTA updates).
- Creating a (executable) .sh file and creating a .conf in ~/.config/upstart, but no success.

Do you guys have any idea on how to make it work?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/a/622484/391744 and http://askubuntu.com/a/630154/391744

Comment: @Velkan I just tried that, but it's not working. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a way to to do that. I will post it here, maybe someone else want it too.

First, in `/home/phablet/Documents`, I created a file called `myfile.sh` with this content:

`#!/bin/sh
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity8 usage-mode Windowed
exit 0`

After that, I created another file in `/home/phablet/.config/upstart` called `jobi.conf` (didn't thought about a better name) with this content:

`description "my script"
start on started msyncd
exec /home/phablet/Documents/myfile.sh`

After that, I just restarted to test it, and it worked.