# Ubuntu Phone: beep every hour

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone

Is there a possibility to make make Ubuntu MX4 phone to beep (make a sound for less then 1s) every hour?

Why do I need it? I used to have my watch which beeps every hour and I would like to have such possibility on my phone too.

Comment: I am not aware that you can do this mad from searching, it doea not look possible yet. However, the pgone should be customizable to individual needs. So raise it in launchpad and see what kind of response you get. If it was anoter app running I just wonder about power usage as Touch can be a little power hungry.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/360592/can-i-set-up-a-cron-job-on-ubuntu-phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until there is a true background tasks/triggers/etc. API in Ubuntu itself this is probably not possible. It **might** hypothetically doable by creating a service that generates a push notification every hour and make your phone beep when it receives it, but I'm not sure if it is possible without adding a custom online account to the system image. Anyway it is kinda crazy idea and would be nothing more then a just-because-I-can solution.